# Wait until element is fully loaded using selenium - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I know there are many ways to make this, I've already tried

```
wait.until(EC.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.CLASS_NAME("market-title-v3")))
```

But I'm trying to search the element INSIDE another element, without call the driver for a fully search on page, and that's the problem (considering the fact that webelement has no attribute called "wait"). What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
root_elm = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
important_elm = root_elm.wait.until(EC.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.CLASS_NAME("market-title-v3")))
```

Can you guys tell me how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
root_elm = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
important_elm = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CLASSNAME, "market-title-v3"))
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually works. Apparently there's no method called "visibilityOfElementLocated"