# Python Selenium How Can I Wait For Xpath Element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to wait for this xpath element until the xpath element I use below opens. How can I do it.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
//div[@class="expander_content"]/ul/li[3]
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65768891/wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded-using-selenium-python/65768951) help.

Comment: Please let me know  if I understand correctly what you asked for and my solution is working for you

Comment: Thanks, the solutions shared in the thread worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach to wait for elements with Selenium is to use Expected Conditions explicit waits.
With the following imports

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And after initializing an instance of the `wait` object like the following

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

You will be able to wait until the element visibility with:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="expander_content"]/ul/li[3]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple **Waits** in selenium but the best one is explicit.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

Now you will be able to apply wait according to your need, there is multiple expected conditions out there or you can customize it:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.Condition(Locator));
```

**Note:** For details please visit [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)